# Search Everything does not always find file with exclamation marks

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, file-search

I have a file called `!!! Readme !!!.txt`. When I search the file with [Search Everything](http://voidtools.com), the following happens:

- search for `Readme` finds the file
- search for `!!!` does not find the file but finds many other things

It seems like `!` acts like a NOT operator, but I can't find a description of it in the help file nor in the Internet FAQ, so I continued:

- search for `\!` finds the file
- search for `\!\!\!` does not file the file

**Is there a way to find files / folders with multiple exclamation marks reliably and only?**

Versions and settings:

```
1.2.1.371 (latest stable when posting)
1.3.3.658b (latest beta when posting)
[x] Match path
[ ] Enable Regex
[ ] Match Case
[ ] Match whole word
[ ] Match diacritics
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to find an alternative and/or contact `Void Tools` for assistance.  Don't even mention what operating system.  Specific solutions might exist, for instance, by default Windows has a good search mechanic.

Comment: I have added OS information. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

If you Enable RegEx   `\!\!\!  or \!!!` will work.

If you disable RegEx `\!!!` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Just after posting my question I find that using `\!!!` does what I want.